# Bootstrap 4 nav dropdown menu overflows the window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have given an example of `navbar` `dropdown` below. When i click the dropdown the menu overflows to the right causing horizontal scroll to appear in the window.

How can i always keep the dropdown menu within the window even in **mobile view** ?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav id="navbar-example2" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">

    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#one">one</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#two">two</a>
        <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#three">three</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Why are you loading 2 versions of jQuery?

Comment: @WebDevBooster edited it. that was a mistake

Comment: @Raj Check my answer it will help you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overwrite the bootstrap CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    right: 0 !important;
    left: auto !important;
}
```

It will work for you

Comment: Overwriting Bootstrap css is generally NOT a good idea. Especially in those cases where the native Bootstrap classes can do the job.

Comment: @WebDevBooster Yes but if we face issue then we need to update. but we should use our class not bootstrap

Comment: Yes, when you add unnecessary css hacks, then, later on, you will need more css hacks to fix the problems caused by the original css hacks. That is definitely true.

Comment: CSS hacks like that make the use of Bootstrap pretty pointless in my opinion. The whole point of Bootstrap is to avoid using css hacks.

Comment: It's now going out of the left side of the screen instead of the right side.

Comment: @HikaruShindo It depends on your existing CSS also. You have to share your CSS first then you can get an answer.

Answer (score 10):

From the bootstrap 4 documentation:

> By default, a dropdown menu is automatically positioned 100% from the top and along the left side of its parent. Add .dropdown-menu-right to a .dropdown-menu to right align the dropdown menu.

So, just add `.dropdown-menu-right` and the menu is going to be right aligned.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for Bootstrap 4 because it does not force to override bootstrap defaults, nor to wrap in a container when not needed. As stated by the documentation : "Navbars and their contents are fluid by default. Use optional containers to limit their horizontal width." (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/#how-it-works)

Comment: Don't be confuse that, you need two classes together, `dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right`

Answer (score 0):

in bootstrap4 , you need to add "dropdown-menu-right" , for example :

```
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right  " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>

  </li>
```

and for bootstrap5 , just add "dropdown-menu-end" for example:

```
        <ul className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr className="dropdown-divider" /></li>
            <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
```

this is just an example , and change it based on your case/requirements.

i hope this helpful for you .

Answer (score -1):

To fix your problem, you simply wrap the navbar in a `container` (or `container-fluid`) class like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav id="navbar-example2" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
   <div class="container">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
       <ul class="nav nav-pills">

           <li class="nav-item dropdown pr-3 pr-sm-2">
               <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
               <div class="dropdown-menu">
                   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#one">one</a>
                   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#two">two</a>
                   <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#three">three</a>
               </div>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Also, the `pr-3 pr-sm-2` classes add a little "padding-right" to the drop-down.

Comment: ok it works on large screen but on smaller screen it still goes out of the window.

Comment: I edited my code snippet. Check it now. The added `pr-3 pr-sm-2` classes add a little "padding-right" to the drop-down.